# In ASP.NET Core allow optional id in route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

My routes are setup like

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

What I want to do is have the URL be like

```
/Company/{cfccc978-bfec-4425-a7ff-77ca7509a807}/Equipment/Index
/Company/{cfccc978-bfec-4425-a7ff-77ca7509a807}/Equipment/Edit/{f3628bf8-0e1d-4ae8-bf78-36feff9dfca5}
OR
/Company/Equipment/Index
/Company/Equipment/Edit/{f3628bf8-0e1d-4ae8-bf78-36feff9dfca5}
```

If the CompanyId is omitted then the value from the logged in user will be used.

If the CompanyId is present then I need to make sure the user has access to it, either they have to have that CompanyId on their user or be in the Admin Role.

I have to admit I am clueless on where to start.

I think I need to modify the areaRoute mapping to include the CompanyID but then how should my controller methods utilize it? I would like to avoid having to code every action method to go pull the companyid from the user to make it as seamless as possible.

This is a new application so anything goes, no need to worry about breaking existing functionality.

Comment: It says if there is a /Areas/{Company/Store/etc}/ folder then use the views from that otherwise try the other routes. It allows for multiple areas without having to have a route for each.

Comment: Currently it doesn't. Thus me posting the question with "What I have, and what I want to happen" --I have to admit I am clueless on where to start.

I think I need to modify the areaRoute mapping to include the CompanyID

Comment: To prevent this from going down a tit-for-tat road, I would request you read the full question. You have already indicated you are not familiar with the areas implementation of aspnetcore as such I feel this question would be better suited to someone with more experience on this. I have indicated in the question that I am unsure how to format the route or the controller to get my desired outcome.